# How to set "MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU" as an environment variable for a python script?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, libraries

When I run a `py` script there is an error like this

```
RuntimeError: To use MKL 2018 with Theano you MUST set "MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU"
              in your environement.
```

I googled why and in the terminal tried

```
export MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU
```

and run again, but the problem still exists. I wanted to check whether the environment variable exists or not, so I tried

```
$ env MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU
env: ‘MKL_THREADING_LAYER’: No such file or directory
```

Does that mean I don't get the environment or what?

Back to the code of the original bug, the problem is this:

```
File "/home/chen/anaconda2/envs/rllab3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/theano/configdefaults.py", line 1251, in check_mkl_openmp
```

This is how the code of the library is designed:

```py
def check_mkl_openmp():
if not theano.config.blas.check_openmp:
    return
import os
if ('MKL_THREADING_LAYER' in os.environ and
        os.environ['MKL_THREADING_LAYER'] == 'GNU'):
    return
try:
    import mkl
    if '2018' in mkl.get_version_string():
        raise RuntimeError('To use MKL 2018 with Theano you MUST set "MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU" in your environement.')
except ImportError:
    raise RuntimeError(""" Could not import 'mkl'.  Either install mkl-service with conda or set MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU in your environment for MKL 2018.
If you have MKL 2017 install and are not in a conda environment you can set the Theano flag blas.check_openmp to False.  Be warned that if you set this flag and don't set the appropriate environment or make sure you have the right version you *will* get wrong results.
""")
```

How can I set this environment variable and make the original code work?

Comment: `env` runs a program in a modified environment, run it like this: `env MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU py /path/to/python/script`

Answer (score 7):

I used

```
conda install mkl=2017
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` file
`export MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU`
then re-open your terminal, it will work

Comment: You can also type `source ~/.bashrc` to avoid having to close your terminal, although this will run everything in `.bashrc`, which you might not want.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and resolved it simply by typing and executing these commands one by one on the terminal.

```
conda install theano
conda install keras
```

I think the error meant that there was no theano installed, anyway, it worked.

Comment: If `theano` is not installed then it cannot be giving an error, can it? Anyway, this didn't work for me (it probably worked for you because installing `keras` induced a downgrade to another version of `theano`, or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

To use MKL 2018 with Theano you MUST set `"MKL_THREADING_LAYER=GNU"` in your environment.
This command would solve your problem

```
conda install mkl=2018
```